# java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/namespace/QName"

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, linkageerror

I am developing an **Eclipse plugin** and I try to replace a normal jar **library** with the equivalent **OSGi bundle**. I use the **Apache Felix** maven-bundle-plugin to build the jar file and convert it to an OSGi bundle. In the pom.xml I define the `<Export-Package>` that I need for my plugin which `uses` the `javax.xml.namespace` package and also define as`<Embed-Dependency>` all the packages (dependencies) that the library contained, including the `javax.xml.namespace` package. When I was using the library in the classpath of the plugin I could run the plugin normally. Now, that I import the packages from the OSGi bundle that I created from the library, I get this error:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/namespace/QName"
```

It seems like two different versions of the `QName` class are instantiated (one from the plugin and one from the library?) but I need this class both in the library and the plugin. I tried importing the javax.xml.namespace package from the bundle into the plugin but this didn't help. Also I tried moving the code related to the library in another class of the plugin where I don't import the `QName` class but this didn't change something. It seems like a tough problem. Do I need to change something in the *MANIFEST.MF* or in the embedded packages of the bundle or do I need to change something in the imported packages of the plugin? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Get rid of the dependency for javax.xml.namespace. You're about 12 years out of date with that. It's built into the JRE.